# It's possible to call ActionScript function from JavaScript web workers?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, web-worker

I have an ActionScript function exposed by ExternalInterface (ExternalInterface.addCallback).

Since the unique parameter of the function is a really big string (~1115468 chars), I'm experiencing some "blocking" on the flash component.

Looking to Chrome's JS profiler I found that this call is the guilty. It's possible to dispatch a web worker to do this job?

I found vkthread (http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/) that promise you can call functions with contexts, but trying to call my heavy function I've received "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author of vkThread plugin already answered this question here:

https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkthread/issues/1

Briefly: context object has a property, which refers to the object itself.  That's why it cannot be stringified with JSON.stringify(...), which is used internally in this plugin.